# How to access From and To routes in Nuxt/Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I am building a Nuxt/Vue application.

In Dev Tools, I see that there is a `From` and `To` property. How to access these in the Nuxt application? I have tried

`this.$nuxt.$route`, `this.$nuxt.$router`, `this.$route` but haven't succeeded yet.

My objective is to get the **previous route**, from where I navigated, on the **current page**.

[image]

Comment: did you try this.$form?

Comment: @H.Udara It is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use these hooks: *beforeRouteEnter*, *beforeRouteUpdate* or *beforeRouteLeave*, as described here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Each hook has these parameters: *from*, *to*, and *next*.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65592158/7762322 by dyon048

I was able to achieve this by doing

```html
<template>
  <nuxt-link :to="prevRoute">Back</nuxt-link>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      prevRoute: '',
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next((vm) => {
      vm.prevRoute = from
    })
  },
}
```